# How do I replace multiple spaces with just one character?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's my code so far:

```
input1 = input("Please enter a string: ")
newstring = input1.replace(' ','_')
print(newstring)
```

So if I put in my input as:

```
I want only    one     underscore.
```

It currently shows up as:

```
I_want_only_____one______underscore.
```

But I want it to show up like this:

```
I_want_only_one_underscore.
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This pattern will replace any groups of whitespace with a single underscore

```
newstring = '_'.join(input1.split())
```

If you only want to replace spaces (not tab/newline/linefeed etc.) it's probably easier to use a regex

```
import re
newstring = re.sub(' +', '_', input1)
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way I could do this with the replace function? or is this pretty much the only way?

Comment: @ajkey94 I don't know why you'd want to use str.replace instead of either of these perfectly good ways to do it, but I added an option in my answer below for you all the same.

Answer (score 6):

Dirty way:

```
newstring = '_'.join(input1.split())
```

Nicer way (more configurable):

```
import re
newstring = re.sub('\s+', '_', input1)
```

Extra Super Dirty way using the `replace` function:

```
def replace_and_shrink(t):
    '''For when you absolutely, positively hate the normal ways to do this.'''
    t = t.replace(' ', '_')
    if '__' not in t:
        return t
    t = t.replace('__', '_')
    return replace_and_shrink(t)
```

Comment: `split()` with no parameters _does_ handle any whitespace

Answer (score 5):

**First approach (doesn't work)**

```
>>> a = '213         45435             fdgdu'
>>> a
'213         45435                            fdgdu                              '
>>> b = ' '.join( a.split() )
>>> b
'213 45435 fdgdu'
```

As you can see the variable a contains a lot of spaces between the "useful" sub-strings. The combination of the split() function without arguments and the join() function cleans up the initial string from the multiple white spaces.

The previous technique fails when the initial string contains special characters such as '\n':

```
>>> a = '213\n         45435\n             fdgdu\n '
>>> b = ' '.join( a.split() )
>>> b
'213 45435 fdgdu'   (the new line characters have been lost :( )
```

In order to correct this we can use the following (more complex) solution.

**Second approach (works)**

```
>>> a = '213\n         45435\n             fdgdu\n '
>>> tmp = a.split( ' ' )
>>> tmp
['213\n', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '45435\n', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'fdgdu\n', '']
>>> while '' in tmp: tmp.remove( '' )
... 
>>> tmp
['213\n', '45435\n', 'fdgdu\n']
>>> b = ' '.join( tmp )
>>> b
'213\n 45435\n fdgdu\n'
```

**Third approach (works)**

This approach is a little bit more pythonic in my eyes. Check it:

```
>>> a = '213\n         45435\n             fdgdu\n '
>>> b = ' '.join( filter( len, a.split( ' ' ) ) )
>>> b
'213\n 45435\n fdgdu\n'
```

Comment: Low quality answer. You could provide some explanations, comments, links to docs and make your answer more readable.

Comment: @goliney
I added some more information in my answer above. Thank your comment.

Comment: Pretty good technical answer; but the formatting is terrible. I'm sorry that I cannot upvote it, because it technically deserves an upvote.